# Is there any working provider for Ethereum Classic APIs?

Tags: infura, ethereum-classic, web3-providers, explorer-api, exchange-api

Provider used for Ethereum is Infura, but there is no any provider for Ethereum Classic.

Previously tested Ethercluster endpoint to access APIs for Ethereum Classic, not able to connect with Kotti endpoint.

Comment: [https://www.ethercluster.com/kotti](https://www.ethercluster.com/kotti) This is not working at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get a response from Ethercluster for ETC with the following curl command:

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x7B98A0", false],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://www.ethercluster.com/etc
```

You can also do the same for Kotti and check its parity node status:

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_nodeStatus","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://www.ethercluster.com/kotti
```

You can also follow the docs for ethercluster to build your own version of Infura: https://docs.ethercluster.com/

Comment: @Yazanator, will you please elaborate more about Ethercluster for Kotti (Testnetwork)? And is all methods of web3 i.e,. eth_getBlockByNumber will be accessible just with ethercluster kotti endpoint?

Comment: @Rudrika Yeah, Kotti is an EVM like other chains, so whatever endpoints Parity provides are available. I provided two working examples for ETC and Kotti that you could have used to answer your own question in the comments, but I'll answer it for you in the hopes that it clarifies things for you.

Yes, Kotti endpoint has eth_getBlockByNumber, here's the curl command to get it for first block:
```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x0", false],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://www.ethercluster.com/kotti
```

Comment: @Yazanator, Alright, does all method of eth/JSON RPC API will work? i.e. 'sendTransaction'.

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://rivet.cloud/. You can get the rpc urls on here